# adding a layout to layout-ldrtl (RTL) cause app to crash

Tags: java, android

i have a login layout which i wanna add it to "layout-ldrtl" folder but when i do it app crashes. when i put it back to "layout" it gets fixed. i assume that android cant detect this Directory. the stacktrace shows my `onCreate` , `setContentView()` method. how can i fix this?

my onCreate Method:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }
```

Error:

```
12-18 12:06:07.957 26220-26220/com.project.amas.layoutdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.project.amas.layoutdesign, PID: 26220
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.amas.layoutdesign/com.project.amas.layoutdesign.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001c
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001c
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:223)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2146)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1151)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.project.amas.layoutdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6982)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2933) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1612) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

i just followed google documentation :

Suppose that you want to add a specific layout file to support RTL scripts, such as the Hebrew, Arabic, and Persian languages. To do this, you add a layout-ldrtl/ directory in your res/ directory, as shown in the following example:

```
res/
    layout/
        main.xml This layout file is loaded by default.
    layout-ldrtl/
        main.xml This layout file is loaded for languages using an
                 RTL text direction, including Arabic, Persian, and Hebrew.
```

Comment: as far as I know you don't have to create a new layout folder for rtl layouts. You just have to define the `layoutDirection` tag in your layouts

Comment: @VivekMishra i'm new to RTL so i'm not sure im doing right. but as i updated my post, i was following documentations. from text if im right i get that its making another Directory for doing this

Comment: you have to keep layout  files in both folders.